# .Net ORM for Hbase/Cassandra/MongoDB

Tags: .net, orm, nosql, kundera

Are there any ORM .Net solutions for working with HBase?  Something similar to the concepts presented in [Kundera](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Basic-Concepts), but a .Net client stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [NoRM](http://normproject.org/) for MongoDB
Here's a sample from their site:

```
public Post GetMostRecentPost()
{
  Post mostRecentPost;

  using(var db = Mongo.Create("mongodb://localhost/BlogApp"))
  {
     var posts = db.GetCollection<Post>();
     //create a LINQ queryable to search the DB.
     var q = posts.AsQueryable();

     //the ordering happens on the server and only one result will be returned.
     mostRecentPost = q.OrderByDescending(y=>y.PostDate).FirstOrDefault();
  }

  return mostRecentPost;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can still use Kundera with  it's REST API. Here it is, have a look at:
https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/tree/trunk/kundera-rest

for reference.

-Vivek